# Bypass no data execution Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to check for two kinds of authorization level for entries in the menu to display according to different levels given to each user.

But the no data exception in oracle sql is preventing me from checking the second table for authorization.

Here is my code:

```
declare 
  v_count number;
  v_name varchar2(255);
begin
  select DASHBOARD into v_count from RCM_ADMINISTRATOR where USER_NAME = :APP_USER;
  select MANAGER into v_name from RCM_ADMINISTRATION_TEAMS where MANAGER = :APP_USER;

  if v_count >= 1 then
    return true;
  end if;
  if v_name is not null then
      return true;
  end if;
  if v_count = 0 then
   return false;
  end if;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 return false;

end;
```

Is there a way to make it so that if I get no data from the first query, I can still run the second query?

Comment: your case is (v_count >= 1 and v_name is not null) ----   (v_count >= 1 or v_name is not null) ???

Comment: @mehmetsahin but if i get no data when running the dashboard query, v_count will not equal anything, and the exception will kick in and return false right away

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem, with many solutions.

One option is to put a BEGIN / EXCEPTION / END block around each SELECT INTO that you're trying to do.

```
declare 
  v_count number;
  v_name varchar2(255);
begin
  BEGIN
    select DASHBOARD into v_count from RCM_ADMINISTRATOR where USER_NAME = :APP_USER;
  EXCEPTION when no_data_found THEN v_count := null;
  END;
  BEGIN
    select MANAGER into v_name from RCM_ADMINISTRATION_TEAMS where MANAGER = :APP_USER;
  EXCEPTION when no_data_found THEN v_name := null;
  END;

  if v_count >= 1 then
  ...etc...
```

I often find it easier just to use MAX:

```
declare 
  v_count number;
  v_name varchar2(255);
begin
  select max(DASHBOARD) into v_count from RCM_ADMINISTRATOR where USER_NAME = :APP_USER;
  select max(MANAGER) into v_name from RCM_ADMINISTRATION_TEAMS where MANAGER = :APP_USER;

  if v_count >= 1 then
  ...etc...
```

It's a lazy technique, and if you aren't careful, it can disguise ORA-01422 errors (exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows). But if you know your query will only return 0 or 1 row, then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. You are using an anonymous block and returning a value, which is not possible. You can write a function which returns a `BOOLEAN` value(`True` or `False`) However, it is of no use because as per Oracle documentation 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG.

> You cannot insert the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` into a database column.
>   You cannot select or fetch column values into a `BOOLEAN` variable.
>   Functions called from a SQL query cannot take any `BOOLEAN` parameters.
>   Neither can built-in SQL functions such as `TO_CHAR`; to represent
>   `BOOLEAN` values in output, you must use `IF-THEN or CASE` constructs to
>   translate `BOOLEAN` values into some other type, such as 0 or 1, 'Y' or
>   'N', 'true' or 'false', and so on.

So In the code, `VARCHAR2` is used as `RETURN` argument.

Pass `APP_USER` as function argument instead of using a bind variable.

For your condition that each query must execute irrespective of exceptions, you can place it in separate `BEGIN..END` blocks.

Once you have used `RETURN` from a stored procedure, you cannot jump back to the rest of the code after exception as you are trying to achieve. Instead, store the value in a variable `exit_code` and `RETURN` using the code before the last `END` to return eventually with an exit code if other conditions are not satisfied.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test_ret(p_app_user IN VARCHAR2)  
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  v_count   NUMBER;
  v_name    VARCHAR2(255);
  exit_code VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT DASHBOARD
    INTO v_count
    FROM RCM_ADMINISTRATOR
    WHERE USER_NAME = p_app_user;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    exit_code := 'FALSE';
  END;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MANAGER
    INTO v_name
    FROM RCM_ADMINISTRATION_TEAMS
    WHERE MANAGER = p_app_user;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    exit_code := 'FALSE';
  END;
  IF v_count >= 1 THEN
    RETURN 'TRUE';
  END IF;
  IF v_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    RETURN 'TRUE';
  END IF;
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    RETURN 'TRUE';
  END IF;
  RETURN exit_code;
END;
/
```

Comment: From their question about authorization in menus, I'm guessing the OP is using Application Express, where it's pretty common to enter anonymous blocks like this into text fields. They're expected to return a value, because the ApEx engine will embed them into built-in functions behind the scenes.

Comment: If so, they should fix the tags on their question.